# Can I use epoxy to repair leak in a full oil tank?

Tags: hvac, welding, oil

I discovered a pinhole leak in my home heating oil tank late last night. I was able to catch the leak before it got too serious, and patched it with JB Weld Tank as a temporary fix.

About 1.5 hours later, the leak made its way through the weld material and was back to dripping. Albeit MUCH slower and more manageable, but not a perfect solve.

My question — will the oil penetration eventually permeate the JB Weld and make it detach from the tank?

I only need this patch for a few weeks until I can convert from oil to gas, but I’m concerned the leak could lubricate the JB Weld and cause it to slip, fully exposing the pinhole again.
Does anyone have experience that might be helpful here?

[image: leak location and patch]

Comment: Was the tank filled and actively leaking when you applied the epoxy?

Comment: Any adhesive wants very clean bare surface to attach to.  This means removing paint and all oil/dirt/gunk before and during curing of the adhesive.  One pinhole probably means more of that area is rusted and just waiting to leak.  I also imagine this is near the bottom.

Comment: @Matthew - correct, the service provider filled the tank a few days ago, and my assumption is the added pressure caused the pinhole to open.

Comment: @crip659 Unfortunately yes, near the bottom. We're hoping to apply enough JB Weld to the entire area to hold us over for the next four weeks, until we can drain the oil and convert to natural gas...

Comment: Consider the mess and cleanup expense when it rips wide open and dumps a full tank of oil on the floor. Your oil provider may have a temporary/portable tank they can rent you for a month to transfer the oil into before that happens.

Comment: It's gonna be hard to get any adhesive to stick to an oily surface.

Comment: Oil tanks do need to be replaced after a while; sounds like you should be budgeting for that. (My solution, since my oil-fired boiler was ancient anyway, was to replace the whole system with a new high-efficiency gas boiler. But I already had gas coming to the house so that was easy.)

Comment: Near the leg is the worst place.  You can expect that leg to collapse/rip a big hole in the tank.  As others have said, get another tank/empty it out now.  If it last the four weeks, start buying lotto tickets.  A full tank will just about ruin the house.  Can google furnace oil leaks.

Comment: Can you support the tank under that bracket to take the force off that bracket?

Comment: how thick is the tank wall? ... a screw could make an effective plug ... use a soft washer that is impervious to oil

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience whatsoever with your proposed solution.

However, I'd suggest that since the oil has already worked its way through the patch, that it won't be long until it's flowing again at the previous rate. Whether it causes the entire spot of JB Weld to come off or just eats its way through doesn't really matter.

Unfortunately, I don't have any good suggestions for you on how to fix this properly.

As a temporary workaround, though, I'd suggest that you contact your oil supply company to detail the issue to them. They *might* be able to come pump oil back out of the tank to get the oil level below the hole. This would

- Prevent a bigger mess
- Allow you to continue heating the house with the remaining oil
- Give you some credit back (I'd think...) for the oil they remove
- You'll probably have to do this anyway once the oil burner is decommissioned so it's a head start.

If they cannot do so (because, maybe, they consider the oil "used" at this point and cannot deal in "used" oil, or they just don't have the capability to pump it back out), ask them to recommend someone who can do this for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the leak is coming from the inside seam between the tank and a leg bracket at the bottom of the tank. Draining the oil past this level would mean we're basically on empty.

Comment: Ooof, that stinks. You may need to work with your oil supplier to drain the tank, then clean & seal it as noted in [JACK's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/289514/34147), then, once the epoxy has cured, have them refill it. Maybe you'd be able to schedule the draining for first thing in the morning, then the refill for last thing in the evening. Yes, your house will cool down during the day and everyone will have to put on a sweatshirt or jacket, but that seems minor compared to having oil just pouring out.

Comment: You may want to note that, as mentioned in the comments, it might not be just this one spot that's at risk, and maybe get to all the leg bracket joints and reinforce them all. It's a hassle, but it's still cheaper than a whole tank of oil drained into your basement.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful stopping an oil leak in a utility transformer but I had to remove some of the oil and totally clean, dry and grind the surface before applying the JB Weld. I caked it on about a quarter inch thick and overlapped the leak by about an inch. There wasn't any pressure in the tank other than gravity. This was a temporary fix until we could get a new transformer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. This might work in our favor, but the leak is coming from the inside seam between the tank and a leg bracket. I'm thinking we can clean the area and apply enough JB Weld to fill the entire bracket, so even if the putty is loose enough to slide, it won't have anywhere to go. https://imgur.com/XZBr2iP

Comment: Looks like the leg might rip right off, from that picture. The weld is separated at the top, just above your patch. and the patch seems to have pulled away from the thing below it, as if there's bulk movement of tank down and leg up. I would definitely inquire about a temporary tank rental.